# How to get current value of progress bar with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying out some new HTML5 form features in the latest version of Opera.

```
<progress value="1" max="10"></progress>
```

What I want to do is to get the current value of the progress bar using jQuery.

I tried...

```
$(function(){
    alert($('progress').val());

});
```

...but it didn't do anything.

How can I get the current value using jQuery?

Comment: ...and? Did it work? What went wrong? Can you provide a demo, at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: [This seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/mgHvw/) but only with the "edge" version of jQuery. 1.6 doesn't work.

Comment: @david thomas: doesn't work. It has no reaction at all.

Comment: thanks to all. Didn't try plain javascript. Before going here. Sorry for the trouble. What I did was this: document.getElementById('prog').value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jQuery's `val()` threw an error for me, so I used the native `value` property.

```
var value = $('progress:first').prop('value');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/VkQqa/).

If using < 1.6, then use `[0].value` to access the native `value` property.